# check if value exists in a group

Tags: sas

I have my desired output table:

```
data work.employees;
    length employee timepoint visit realvisit $30;
    input employee $ timepoint $ visit $ realvisit $;
    datalines;
Smith 1 Screening Screening
Smith 1 Randomization Randomization
Williams 1 Screening Baseline
Williams 2 Randomization Randomization
Jones 1 Visit1 Visit1
Jones 2 Visit3 Visit3
;
run;
```

and I want to to derive realvisit such that in a group of (Employee, Timepoint), if there is no record where visit = Randomization and visit = Screening, then realvisit = Baseline.

Realvisit in the above table is already derived correctly as an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
        proc sort data = work.employees;
        by employee timepoint;
        run;
        
        data work.employees2;
        set work.employees;
        by employee timepoint;
        
        if visit = 'Randomization' then exists = "Y";
            else exists = "N";
            
        if visit = 'Screening' and exists = "N" then
            realvisit = 'Baseline';
        run;
```

Comment: So when there is no RANDOMIZATION visit for someone you want to recode SCREENING to BASELINE?  Is the second visit variable in your input data what you are trying to derive?  Why are you including TIMEPOINT in the BY group?  EMPLOYEE plus TIMEPOINT seems to form a unique key, so there is nothing to search over if you include TIMEPOINT in the grouping.

Comment: Yep that's right. If there's no randomization visit in a unique group of employee/timepoint, then screening should be recoded to baseline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check the whole group.

You could use a double DOW loop.  The first one to check. The second to re-read the data so you can write it back out.

```
data work.employees2;
  do until (last.timepoint);
    set work.employees;
    by employee timepoint;
    if visit = 'Randomization' then exists = "Y";
  end;        
  do until (last.timepoint);
    set work.employees;
    by employee timepoint;
    if visit = 'Screening' and exists ne "Y" then realvisit = 'Baseline';
    output;
  end;        
run;
```